# How to override the 'From' parameter in Grails mail plugin

Tags: email, grails, configuration, groovy, grails-plugin

After installing the grails mail plugin, when I tried to use the ff code:

```
mailService.sendMail {
  to recipients.toArray()
  from "${userEmail}"
  subject "${url?.article?.title}"
  html g.render(template:"/promote/email_template", model: [newsUrl : newShortUrl, news : url?.article, comment: status, user : user, rootUrl : rootUrl])
}
```

But the `from` parameter return NOT the data of userEmail but of the email used in the config file. Is there a way to override this and use another data (the userEmail)?

I assumed that since the From parameter could be used, I can set it with whatever email the current user is using.

Answer (score 2):

I use the `from` method successfully, but I also left out the `grails.mail.default.from` configuration.  The docs say it should work as you expect.  Is your outgoing SMTP server by chance overriding it back to your login?